# is it possible to convert a Gzip byte array to String?

Tags: java, android, compression

i am able to compress a base64 string areng the GZIP java compression method, so it is possible to get the compressed value in a st
ring?

Comment: you can do exact same how you did with a base64 string

Comment: I would think that putting a binary array into a String would cause intermittent bugs.

Comment: If you have a base64 string then you have de encoded value in a string.

Comment: I have compressed the string, but the compressed string returns a byteArray, now I want to convert that byteArray to string...

Comment: In essence what I want to do is to be able to shorten a string, let's say I have a 200 characters long string, I want to be able to compress it to another string with shorter length, and still able to decompress to its original 200 characters string

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can decompress gzip to string with this method.

```
public static String decompress(byte[] byteArray) throws Exception {
    if (byteArray == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzis, "UTF-8"));
    String outputString = "";
    String line;
    while ((line=bfr.readLine())!=null) {
      outputString += line;
    }
    return outputString;
 }
```